# .Net SHA256Managed produce non valid hashing

Tags: .net, hash, cryptography, sha256

I'm writing a function to produce a SHA256 hash on a file.
Here is the code I use

```
public string ComputeHash(Byte[] inputBytes)
    {
        Byte[] hashedBytes = new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        return BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes);
    }
```

Very simple. The fact is that the hashing produced seems not to be valid, according on a couple of tool I tried and, in effect, is different from any other sha256 string I ever seen (and is not even 256 byte).
One result, for example is

```
12-10-B2-60-24-75-11-95-B5-F7-F6-64-39-C3-22-9F-E7-E7-D4-13-69-18-99-C5-A7-C5-EC-2F-E2-D6-09-19
```

Even if I trim out every - char, everything is uppercase, while I always saw lowercase rappresentation. (Is that a problem too) I'm wondering if I'm using the library in a correct way.
please help

Comment: Try `return string.Concat(hashedBytes.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SHA-256 means 256 *bits*, aka 32 *bytes* which is what you're seeing.

Lower-case and upper-case are irrelevant here - that's just the representation of the *bytes* as a string. Ditto whether or not there are hyphens between the bytes. Different tools produce different hex string representations, that's all... so I'd expect "1210B2" to be equivalent to "12-10-b2" etc.

Comment: Do you think there's a better way of getting the string representation, instead of using BitConverter.ToString method?

Comment: @themarcuz: That entirely depends on what you're trying to achieve. It's fine in that it's easy to inspect the output, and the bytes are easy to identify due to the dashes between them.